# Select doesn't iterate within gremlin query. Help requested

Tags: gremlin

I've tried slicing and dicing this query multiple ways in order to allow the DB to a majority of the bulk processing vs. on the client side. To do this I plan on injecting a map, we can start with the two in the example below. Unfortunately merging or adding coalesce logic using hasLabel() and other results in the actual iteration of the list not happening. Example below:

The query below is what I'm trying to get to work. Unfortunately it seems to return the same ID. This tells me it's not iterating once fired off.

```
g.inject(
  [
    [stock_height:111, sh_id:"sh123", inputs: [house: "inputhouse123ia"], outputs: [[house: "outputhouse123oa", group_id: "gid-123a"],[house: "outputhouse123ob", group_id: "gid-123b"]]],
    [stock_height:111, sh_id:"sh1234", inputs: [house: "inputhouse1234ia"], outputs: [[house: "outputhouse1234oa", group_id: "gid-1234a"],[house: "outputhouse1234ob", group_id: "gid-1234b"]]]
  ]).
  unfold().as('sh').
  select('outputs').
  unfold().as('output').select('group_id').as('gid').
  mergeV([(label): 'Peoplegroup']).property('group_id', select('gid')).id()
```

Output:
[ 17846400, 17846400, 17846400, 17846400 ]

Using select outside of addV() or mergeV() seems to work fine.

```
g.inject(
  [
    [stock_height:111, sh_id:"sh123", inputs: [house: "inputhouse123ia"], outputs: [[house: "outputhouse123oa", group_id: "gid-123a"],[house: "outputhouse123ob", group_id: "gid-123b"]]],
    [stock_height:111, sh_id:"sh1234", inputs: [house: "inputhouse1234ia"], outputs: [[house: "outputhouse1234oa", group_id: "gid-1234a"],[house: "outputhouse1234ob", group_id: "gid-1234b"]]]
  ]).
  unfold().as('sh').
  select('outputs').
  unfold().as('output').select('group_id').as('gid').
  select('gid')
```

Output: [ "gid-123a", "gid-123b", "gid-1234a", "gid-1234b" ]

Any ideas? I'm at a loss of new ideas, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was hoping to add 4 new gid vertices to the graph, or return the id's which already exist. The map up could be simplified for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `mergeV` is only matching on a label, the first time it is executed, none exist. So it creates a `Peoplegroup` node. After that each of the other `mergeV` find that initial one. You will notice that by the end the property is actually set to `gid-1234b` (the last one) as it has matched each one and replaced the property. To get a different behavior you need to introduce something more unique to match on, or just inject the whole map and not use `property` at all.

You can actually observe this behavior by changing the cardinality on the `property` step to `list`:

```java
gremlin> g.inject(
......1>   [
......2>     [stock_height:111, sh_id:"sh123", inputs: [house: "inputhouse123ia"], outputs: [[house: 
"outputhouse123oa", group_id: "gid-123a"],[house: "outputhouse123ob", group_id: "gid-123b"]]],
......3>     [stock_height:111, sh_id:"sh1234", inputs: [house: "inputhouse1234ia"], outputs: [[house
: "outputhouse1234oa", group_id: "gid-1234a"],[house: "outputhouse1234ob", group_id: "gid-1234b"]]]
......4>   ]).
......5>   unfold().as('sh').
......6>   select('outputs').
......7>   unfold().as('output').select('group_id').as('gid').
......8>   mergeV([(label): 'Peoplegroup']).property(list,'group_id', select('gid')).id()
==>14
==>14
==>14
==>14        

gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[id:14,label:Peoplegroup,group_id:[gid-123a,gid-123b,gid-1234a,gid-1234b]]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to review my original question. I appreciate it.

In that case, shouldn't the following work? It does not.

`mergeV([(label): 'Peoplegroup', 'group_id': select('gid')])`

Result:
`Failed to execute query, see error details below:
The traversal strategies are complete and the traversal can no longer be modulated`

Comment: `mergeV` is expecting to receive a map, or a traversal that yields a map. In the above case, you have a `select` inside of a map.

Comment: So basically, select doesn't work within mergeV(). What's the recommended approach to dynamically passing in a list of values via inject?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is inject a list of maps and `unfold` them, where each map contains everything required. If that is not sufficient additional properties can be set as part of the `onMerge` and `onMatch` options.